# Is there any reason to define CSS classes in SASS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

In this Bootstrap 4 tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDSkqQft92o&time_continue=24&app=desktop @ 14:44, he redefines Bootstrap classes in his `style.scss` file.

style.scss:

```
.navbar {
  width:100%;
  background: none !important;

  @media(max-width:34em){
    background:black !important;
  }

  .nav-bar-toggler {
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:0;
  }
}
```

What is the advantage? Since it is just CSS, shouldn't it go in the style.css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* go into the style.css file: You don't write that file yourself, but it's rendered from the sass file, therfore you write *everything* into the sass file.

Comment: If you aren't creating SASS variables, is there any reason to use SASS? If all he did was the above, wouldn't it be better to just define it in the style.css file?

Comment: If you don't use the advantages of SASS, there is no reason to use it. But it does have advantages, for example defining variables for colors, borders, whatever. And being able to change them all at once by only changing the variable value is a very useful thing.

Comment: Yes - I've heard that argument but isn't that what a CSS class is for?

Comment: If I have the SASS paradigm right for the OP, basically you create the scss file and work within it. This gives you the option to use SASS. You can still do straight CSS in the SASS file. But at least the SASS option is always available if you want it. Does that sound right?

Comment: yes, that sounds right. But also, you can for example create a color variable and use it in any class - you *don't* have to put it it a separate class and use two classes on every element that you want to assign that color, but just use that variable, and that way also change the color settings in your class definitions.

Comment: @4thSpace You can also have functions, mixins (reusable blocks of code) and do calculations in your scss files, which is far beyond the capability of pure CSS

Answer (score 2):

SASS is a CSS preprocessor and whatever you code in SASS will become CSS eventually. Basically SASS is just CSS with Variables, Nesting, and many more. You can check more here http://sass-lang.com/guide.

I checked the vid for like 3 secs and I think he's just showing how to use SASS specifically the Nesting feature.